# Does IDEA recognize Play Scala template changes?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I'm finding that IntelliJ IDEA 12 doesn't understand changes to Scala templates. For example, suppose I have index.html.scala with this:

```
@(message: String)
```

And my controller calls it using:

```
return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
```

And then I change the template to be:

```
@(message: String, foo: String)
```

And the controller to be:

```
return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready.", "foo"));
```

I'm finding that IDEA will mark the controller code as red, claiming that I have an extra argument ("foo") that I shouldn't have. It isn't until I hit the page and Play recompiles the template that the error highlighting goes away.

Of course, this is a big problem because the whole point of IDEA's excellent syntax highlighting is to allow me to ensure my code is good before I load up the browser. The way the current behavior works, my flow is code->reload->check errors instead of the preferred code->check errors->reload.

Anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: The best thing I've found so far is to open the play console on the command line and run the ~compile command. Then at least the recompile happens when the files change, though it's still not the experience I expect from IDEA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Play waits for next request (i.e. manual refresh of the page in the browser) to involve hot-reload (and recompile changed elements).

Run your app with `play ~run`, so it will be reloading right after file's saving. and changed params will be visible to Idea 12 just in next few seconds

Comment: Yeah, that's basically the same thing as ~compile (which I mentioned as a followup comment to my post). But my frustration is that it's still not the normal behavior you'd expect from IDEA. Also, because IDEA doesn't save files to disk until the IDE loses focus, you still have to tab away to another app, which breaks the normal flow. Bummer :(

Comment: Press `CTRL+S` it will save all files and recompile changed elements in the background, where's the problem ???
And believe me, the continous re-compilation is last thing you would like to see, it would burn your CPU

Comment: Even with CTRL+S, IDEA won't notice the changes to the underlying recompiled class until you tab away and re-focus. It has to do with the "synchronization" setting (see Preferences->General->Synchronization->Synchronize files on frame activation).

Comment: I should add: I don't actually want it to recompile all the time. I just want IDEA to notice the syntax change. This is no different that how I can change a method signature in my Java code and it'll highlight errors. That's the whole point of a strongly typed language: you can have smart IDEs that highlight errors _before_ compiling.

Comment: That's the way the Play works, go into your Java controller and keeping CTRL click on the index.render(...) you'll see that will move you to the COMPILED version of the Scala view. In other words, Play MUST to compile views with new params, to make them visible and type-aware... remember, that behavior of default params in Java and Scala are different, and without recompilling it wasn't possible to work properly in Java controllers

Comment: I think you're still misunderstanding me: I'm not questioning how _Play_ works, I'm questioning how the IDE works. It does auto complete and syntax highlighting for Java and Scala just fine without compiling, but it appears this particular issue may just be a bug. There is no reason IDEA couldn't parse the syntax of the templates (_without_ compiling) and do proper syntax highlighting automatically.

Comment: Now I understand, I'm afraid, that Play + Idea is best option currently anyway. I agree with you that would be better if the task could be done with plugin. but... we have to wait :)

Comment: Yeah - was hoping someone out here in SO would have some trick to make this work better. Not the end of the world, since template parameters don't change often, but still not as nice as it could be. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

i just typed it into a google : http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin?pluginId=7080

Comment: I have that plugin already installed - that's not the problem.